# Why is this Persisted field not calculating correctly - [FIELDA]='%BUILD%'

Tags: sql, sql-server, persisted-column

I have a persisted field in SQL Server 2008.

```
(case when [FIELDA]='%BUILD%' then CONVERT([bit],(1),(0)) else CONVERT([bit],(0),(0)) end)
```

FIELDA can contain 'LARGEBUILDING' , 'BUILDING', 'BUILDING MAJOR'm, so BUILDING can be anywhere in the string.

The persisted field is not generating a no '0' value when FIELD A contains 'BUILD', why is this?

Comment: Do you mean LIKE rather than = ?

Comment: You shouldn't check for equality `[FIELDA]='%BUILD%'` but rather you need to use `LIKE` : `[FIELDA] LIKE '%BUILD%'`

Answer (score 0):

I should have used:

```
[FIELDA]like'%BUILD%'
```